# How to interact with the deployed ERC20(openzeppelin ERC20 contract) token and transfer token from user address X to address Y?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, erc20, openzeppelin

I've created a simple Contract extending openzeppelin ERC20.
I'm trying to transfer token from one address to another.

Contract code is as below:

File name: Token.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
    uint256 public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 100000;

    constructor() ERC20("My Token", "MYT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }
}
```

Code within test file:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Send token from second address in the block", function () {

    it("Send 100 MYT to the third account", async function () {

        const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
        const token = await Token.deploy();

        // get accounts from the network
        const [owner, secondAccount, thirdAccount] = await ethers.getSigners();

        // send some credit to the second account
        await token.transfer(secondAccount.address, 500);

        // Approve token transfer
        await token.approve(secondAccount.address, 200);

        // Transfer credit from second account to the third account (This step is not working)
        await token.transferFrom(secondAccount.address, thirdAccount.address, 100);
    });
});
```

Error received:

```
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance'
      at Token.sub (@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol:171)
      at Token.transferFrom (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:154)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
      at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:63:3)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:501:9)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
      at EthModule._estimateGasAction (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:421:9)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:105:18)
      at EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If you check Approve if [erc20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20), the function arguments expect `address _spender, uint256 _value` as arguments. In your case you approved `secondAccount` to withdraw 200 tokens.

It means `secondAccount` can transfer those token to his account from the `token` contract. To do that, you try `await token.connect(secondAccount).transferFrom(token.address,secondAccount.address,100);`

Comment: Thank you Aditya for the answer. What you said above is correct but I'm trying to transfer token from Second Account to Third Account. Tell me if I need to add or remove the lines in the code.

Comment: To transfer tokens from `secondAccount` to `thirdAccount`. You first have to transfer the tokens to `secondAccount` from `token` contract and call `transfer` function from `secondAccount`. Or `secondAccount` can give access to `thirdAccount` and then `thirdAccount` can call `transferFrom`.